# PGFplots: no mark is showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have standard deviation bars but there is no symbol mark.  How can I get one to appear?

I took the statistical code from [TikZ: How to pass a specific table to \pgfplotstableset if used for tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176131/tikz-how-to-pass-a-specific-table-to-pgfplotstableset-if-used-for-tikzpicture)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}

%% Code chunk for statistics starts here...
\newcommand{\calcrowmean}{
  \def\rowmean{0}
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index}+1}
  \edef\numberofcols{\pgfmathresult}
  % ... loop over all columns, summing up the elements
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}}{
    \pgfmathparse{\rowmean+\thisrowno{\col}/\numberofcols}
    \edef\rowmean{\pgfmathresult}
  }
}
\newcommand{\calcstddev}{
  \def\rowstddev{0}
  \calcrowmean
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}}{
    \pgfmathparse{\rowstddev+(\thisrowno{\col}-\rowmean)^2/(\numberofcols-1)}
    \edef\rowstddev{\pgfmathresult}
  }
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\rowstddev)}
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  mystat/.style = {
    summary statistics/start index/.initial=1,
    summary statistics/end index/.initial=3,
    create col/mean/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/create col/assign/.code={% In each row ... 
        \calcrowmean
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\rowmean
      }
    },
    create col/standard deviation/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/create col/assign/.code={% In each row ... 
        \calcstddev
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
      }
    }
  }
}
%% ...code chunk for statistics ends here

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{inhibdata.txt}
  x rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4 rep5 rep6 rep7 rep8
  -6.60206 0.4707758 0.471134 0.464 0.4738401 0.4835494 0.4763314 0.4777448 0.4634806
  -6.60206 0.2826772 0.2869296 0.2830769 0.2863636 0.2739131 0.2830051 0.2679083 0.263196
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{
  mystat,
  create on use/mean/.style={create col/mean},
  create on use/stddev/.style={create col/standard deviation}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    align = center,
    xmin = -8.6,
    xmax = -5,
    ymin = 0.15,
    ymax = 0.65,
    xtick = {-8, -7, ..., -5}
    ]
    \addplot[only marks, mark = circle, red, error bars/.cd, y dir = both,
    y explicit] table[x = x, y = mean, y error = stddev]{inhibdata.txt};
    \legend{$Z' = 0.757$}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I believe since the sd bars are so small `pgfplots` wont put in a symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `mark=circle` is valid. But, using `mark = o` works, but not really sure that that this useful to show the error bars in that case:

[image]

### Notes:

- To get a solid circle use `mark = *`, and `mark size=0.5pt` to adjust the size if desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}

%% Code chunk for statistics starts here...
\newcommand{\calcrowmean}{
  \def\rowmean{0}
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index}+1}
  \edef\numberofcols{\pgfmathresult}
  % ... loop over all columns, summing up the elements
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}}{
    \pgfmathparse{\rowmean+\thisrowno{\col}/\numberofcols}
    \edef\rowmean{\pgfmathresult}
  }
}
\newcommand{\calcstddev}{
  \def\rowstddev{0}
  \calcrowmean
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/start index},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/summary statistics/end index}}{
    \pgfmathparse{\rowstddev+(\thisrowno{\col}-\rowmean)^2/(\numberofcols-1)}
    \edef\rowstddev{\pgfmathresult}
  }
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\rowstddev)}
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  mystat/.style = {
    summary statistics/start index/.initial=1,
    summary statistics/end index/.initial=3,
    create col/mean/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/create col/assign/.code={% In each row ... 
        \calcrowmean
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\rowmean
      }
    },
    create col/standard deviation/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/create col/assign/.code={% In each row ... 
        \calcstddev
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
      }
    }
  }
}
%% ...code chunk for statistics ends here

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{inhibdata.txt}
  x rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4 rep5 rep6 rep7 rep8
  -6.60206 0.4707758 0.471134 0.464 0.4738401 0.4835494 0.4763314 0.4777448 0.4634806
  -6.60206 0.2826772 0.2869296 0.2830769 0.2863636 0.2739131 0.2830051 0.2679083 0.263196
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{
  mystat,
  create on use/mean/.style={create col/mean},
  create on use/stddev/.style={create col/standard deviation}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    align = center,
    xmin = -8.6,
    xmax = -5,
    ymin = 0.15,
    ymax = 0.65,
    xtick = {-8, -7, ..., -5}
    ]
    \addplot[only marks, mark = o, red, error bars/.cd, y dir = both,
    y explicit] table[x = x, y = mean, y error = stddev]{inhibdata.txt};
    \legend{$Z' = 0.757$}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any way to get a solid circle?  It is from lab data so if it covers the standard dev that is fine.

Comment: @dustin: Added notes section in solution for that.